# Low Mouse Battery Optional For Future Releases

Tags: battery

Can we put an option to disallow the mouse low battery message in the next release?

Thank you; Sherman

Comment: Next release? The one that would come after Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Why? Would you rather be taken by surprise, starting with a "dead mouse" initial problem state?

Comment: Seems like we would create a whole new class of 100% preventable "*Ubuntu broke my mouse*" questions and complaints. We would be tediously asking myriad users to try a fresh battery in their mouse, tolerating arguments from cranks who claim that their battery can't be dead (but won't simply check), and closing questions by fools who want a "workaround" since they cannot conveniently obtain a fresh battery for assorted silly reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, AskUbuntu is the wrong place to ask for new features for Ubuntu.

The third-best way to ask for a new feature in Ubuntu is to file a Wishlist Bug on http://www.launchpad.net against whatever package creates that battery warning.

The second-best way to ask for a new feature in Ubuntu is to volunteer to help with the upstream project that creates the software. After you get to know the developers for a few months, and understand the code and the goals and the constraints of the upstream source, your request will have much greater influence. After all, you're asking a *friend* for a simple favor.

The best way to ask for a new feature in Ubuntu is to directly contribute the code for the feature to the upstream project, and to have the contribution approved by your new friend there. From there, the next upstream release will flow to Debian, then to a future release of Ubuntu.

The latter two methods (participation in Free Software projects) are the way that most new features get developed. Wishlist bugs tend to languish.